# How to cancel this file upload below

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a a form which contains a file input, upload button and cancel button:

```
<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='stopImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
<p class='imagef1_upload_form' align='center'><label>Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label>
<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>
</p>
<p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'>
<label><input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>
</p> 
<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe>
</form>
```

I have set up the php to upload the file and all that and the uploading works perfectly. The uploading starts and stops because of the javascript functions below but what my question is that how can it be coded so that when the user starts uploading (startImageUpload() function), if the user wishes to cancel the upload during uploading by clicking on the cancel button, then it stops the uploading (I believe it needs to navigate to the stopImageUpload() function but I am not sure if this is correct or not).

I have set up everything to display on the screen correctly, I just need to know what is the right function to be able to successfully cancel an upload as well as displaying the message 'There is an error during uploading' which is already in the stopImageUpload() function.

Below is the function where the upload starts:

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;
      return true;
}
```

Below is the function where the upload finishes:

```
function stopImageUpload(success){
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden');
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden');

      return true;   
}
```

Comment: Unless your uploading is ajaxed there is no way to stop the browser doing the request only the user can do that.

Comment: Post a message to the server and tell it to stop the uploading.

Comment: Where is your request handle?

Comment: Guys, I have sorted uploading and all that, I just want to know how to finish the cancel button function so that when the button is clicked, it straight away goes onto the stopImageUpload so that it stops the upload. If there is a way to code it so it stops the file upload then how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so you already have the function and the click handler, so what's stopping you from calling your function within your event handler?

Assuming that the stopImageUpload function is within the same file (or at least loaded on that page):

```
$(".imagecancel").on("click", function(event) {
    console.log("clicked");
    event.preventDefault();
    stopImageUpload(); // Just call it?!
});
```

Also, make sure to have the browser stop sending it's current request (upload) in your stopImageUpload function:

```
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    window.document.execCommand('Stop');
} else {
    window.stop();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am working with a partner who will put this code in an application and design the app. Can the navigator.appName be used for apps such as Flex, Flash Builder or Cold fusion (I don't know which software the application is on)?

Comment: This is just plain javascript, it has nothing to do with any of those languages, it interacts directly with the browser.